# Does the StackExchange API have a WSDL file?

Tags: support

The title pretty much says it all: Does the StackExchange API have a WSDL file to help implement access to the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the API docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs); there is [no mention of a WSDL file](https://www.google.com/search?q=WSDL%20site%3aapi.stackexchange.com) for the API.

Further, WSDL is *typically* used for old XML and/or SOAP API's.  Since the Stack Exchange API is JSON based, it seems *unlikely* that an official WSDL exists.

(The API docs also make no mention of XML or SOAP.)